# ERROR in MAP SIDE JOIN in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, join, hive

I found we have to set the below property if want to run only map phase in join.i.e reduce=0.then i am getting error as below.if i set the property as false map-reduce run and join happens sucsessfully.

```
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join=true; 

hive> set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize=(default it will be 25MB);
Query returned non-zero code: 1, cause: 'SET hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize=(default it will be 25MB)' FAILED because hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize expects LONG type value.
hive> SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(expense) */ c.ID, c.NAME, o.AMOUNT, o.DATE FROM emp c CROSS JOIN expense o ON (c.ID = o.emp_ID);
Query ID = acadgild_20161226234949_6ede202c-7f91-42ac-a0c9-3b2617fad0ae
Total jobs = 1
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/acadgild/hadoop-2.6.0/bin/hadoop" (in directory "/home/acadgild"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.executeInChildVM(MapredLocalTask.java:289)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask.execute(MapredLocalTask.java:137)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1604)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:410)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:783)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:616)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 23 more
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask
hive> set hive.auto.convert.join=false;                                                                                  
hive>
```

Answer (score 0):

Map Side Join in Hive can be performed in two ways.

1. By specifying the keyword, `/*+ MAPJOIN(b) */` in the join statement.
2. By setting the following property to true.

   hive.auto.convert.join=true

I think you are trying to combine both the ways. Please check this blog for more info [link](https://acadgild.com/blog/map-side-joins-in-hive/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, the program can't find the native hadoop libraries at /home/acadgild/
What you can do is, try run the below command:

```
cp -r /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/ /home/acadgild/
```

Now go into hive and try to do that and it should work.